# Не кто иной / некто иной

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, местоимения

Как правильно? (Я думаю, что 2-й вариант правильный.)

1. Это был не Леопольд. Это был **некто** иной.
2. Это был не Леопольд. Это был **не кто** иной.

[некто иной; не кто иной](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9.%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9.&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. По правилам подходит первая запись (обратим внимание на ударение):  Это был не Леопольд. *Это был **нЕкто** иной.*

**НЕКТО**, других форм нет; местоим. сущ. Некий человек, кто-то.

2. Второй вариант (с раздельным написанием НЕ) пишется в одно предложение (противопоставление, отрицательная конструкция): *Это был **не кто инОй**, как  Леопольд.*

Answer (score 3):

• В словарях имеется вот что:
**не́кто** (мест. неопр., местоим. нескл., местоим. сущ., неопр. мест.) — неопределённое лицо, какой-то человек, кто-то, некий человек.

В Нацкорпусе — вот что:
*В эти дни я уже не я, а **некто иной**, помнящий притом, что был совсем недавно мною, и оттого страдающий еще пуще* (Геннадий Алексеев. Зеленые берега);
*И вот как бы приподнят над землей, и уже не простой, безвестный казак он, Емельян Пугачёв, а **некто иной**, неведомый и странный* (В. Я. Шишков. Емельян Пугачев).

Без изменений, думаю, верна первая запись (не́кто иной = кто-то иной, кто-то другой):
*Это был не Леопольд. Это был не́кто иной.*
(Можно записать одним предложением: *Это был не Леопольд, а некто иной.*)

•• Вторая запись требует "добавки":
*Это был не Леопольд. Это был не кто иной, как его брат-близнец.*

> Сочетания ***не кто иной (другой), как*** и ***не что иное (другое), как*** выражают противопоставление; в них ***не*** является отрицательной частицей и пишется раздельно, например: *Разрешение может дать **не кто иной, как** руководитель учреждения; Горение — это **не что иное, как** соединение данного вещества с кислородом воздуха.*

В Нацкорпусе:
*Это **был не кто иной, как** поэт-солдат Аполлон Грибочуев* (Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть);
*Это **был не кто иной, как** Вальтер Шелленберг, бригаденфюрер СС, генерал-майор полиции...* (Вадим Кожевников. Щит и меч);
*Присмотревшись, Незнайка убедился, что это **был не кто иной, как** всем известный милиционер Свистулькин* (Николай Носов. Незнайка в Солнечном городе).

[Отрицательные местоимения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/32.htm) (Розенталь)